# While statement isn't excuting inside if statement?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to make it print out a range of specified numbers.  So if they select option 1 and put in 1 and 15, I want it to print out 1 to 15.  Once it gets to the while statement though it just prints nothing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Please choose your choice from the following menu");
    
    System.out.print("\n1) Print through all integer numbers between two given integers");
    System.out.print("\n2) Display a right triangular pattern of stars");
    System.out.println("\n3) Quit");
    
    int userInput = in.nextInt();
    
    if (userInput == 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter the start number: ");
        int firstInteger = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
        int secondInteger = in.nextInt();
        
    while (firstInteger < secondInteger); 
        System.out.print(firstInteger);
        firstInteger++;
    
    
    }   else if (userInput == 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter the height: ");
            int triangleHeight = in.nextInt();
            
    }   else if (userInput == 3);{
            System.exit(userInput);
            
    }
    
    in.close();
}

}
```

Comment: while (firstInteger < secondInteger);  your while stops at the ;

Comment: I changed this but now the program doesn't end and just has a blank page.

Comment: changed it how? just by removing the ;? in that case the while block only contains the print statement, it doesn't change the value of firstInteger, because that is after the first ;, meaning it's after the repetitive block

Answer (score 1):

You should change :

```
while (firstInteger < secondInteger); 
        System.out.print(firstInteger);
        firstInteger++;
```

to

```
 while (firstInteger < secondInteger) {
        System.out.print(firstInteger);
        firstInteger++;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you.  I have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer.  Also is there a reason I have to open and close the while statement but I don't have to close that first if statement before I put the while statement?

Comment: you don't have to use {'s, same as with if statements, but if you don't, the first ; reached marks the end of the block

Answer (score 0):

```
while (firstInteger < secondInteger);
```

This will be treated as two executable lines of instructions,
which is similar like

```
while (firstInteger < secondInteger)
                ;
```

Try to remove the `;` after while statement

Comment: which will result in an infinite loop, so even though it "solves" the issue, it creates a new one